# Magento: Product inventory reduction after order code?

Tags: magento

Does anyone know where the code that reduces the inventory by one on products ordered after an order is completed is located? Ive combed through the checkout folders and cant seem to locate it.

Im assuming its something like:

1. Order is placed
2. Array of products ordered
3. Deducts "1" from each inventory number

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find what your looking for in Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status.php

There are a variety of events that you can leverage from there.  Also note that any changes to inventory are managed through here.  So, not just when an order is placed but also manual changes to inventory etc.